# What is the probability that two random-floats will be the same?

Tags: netlogo

How is the netlogo float defined and how does how reliable is random-float as a method for producing reliably unique numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm used by `random-float` is known as the [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister). (That fact is documented at http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#random.)

Comment: Seth, the limit on the range of seeds suggests that it's using a 32-bit Mersenne Twister. Is that correct?

Comment: Perhaps, but see my comment on the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/);

> All numbers in NetLogo are stored internally as double precision floating point numbers, as defined in the IEEE 754 standard. They are 64 bit numbers consisting of one sign bit, an 11-bit exponent, and a 52-bit mantissa. See the IEEE 754 standard for details.

How reliable "random float" is to generate unique numbers depends greatly on the algorithm used, however a sequence of truly random numbers are in no way *guaranteed* to be unique, just *likely* to be.

Comment: 1 in 2^64 , 1 in 1.8446744e+19

Comment: @King-Ink If the algorithm produces perfectly uniform numbers _and you only draw 2 numbers_, yes, the likelihood of them colliding would be in the vicinity of 1 in 2^64. In practice, probably at least slightly worse, with some algorithms very much worse.

Comment: And note that 1E19 is an absolutely enormous number. The expected time it would take to get the same number twice would be measured in centuries.

Comment: This is actually slightly off since you'll basically never been drawing from the full spectrum of random numbers. So, supposing we're using `random-float 1`, we're fixing the sign (1 bit) of the number, and the sign of the exponent (another bit), so it's actually more like 1 in 2^62, or 1 in 4.61168601843e+18.

Comment: Further, this doesn't take into account the Mersenne Twister algorithm itself. It looks like NetLogo is using the classic 32-bit variant. So I suppose that would actually be 1 in 2^30, or 1 in 1073741824. I could be wrong about this though.

Comment: Maybe when you ask the 32-bit version for a double (64 bits), it generates two 32-bit integers and then combines them somehow into a single 64-bit double? I would certainly hope that's what it does.

Comment: So the chance of getting two times the same numbers is 1 in 2^64?